# CSS Random spacing, help please

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, and I can't seem to figure out what causes the gap between the 'Over' and 'Contact' part at the bottom of the page.

Can anyone spot te problem?

[LINK](http://i300486.iris.fhict.nl/portfolio/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#over h1, footer h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

First, post relevant code in the question.

Regarding your question . The margin is the `h1` inside the `footer`.

So, try this:

```
footer h1 {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The target webpage will change or dissappear, if we want a question to perhaps be of use for someone else in the future, it should have code within the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
#over {
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #2BB;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Here you specify that the "Over mij" section should have a minimal height of 100% of your screen, that's what causing the gap. Remove it or reduce the value to change it.